# Tools for making a site design mobile phone friendly

Tags: iphone, mobile-phones

What tools helps designing sites which would be mobile phone friendly ? Something that would product the right CSS, the right html, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt you'll find too much that would make good markup for mobile phones across the board.

Here is a table for compatibility for different mobile browsers: http://www.quirksmode.org/m/table.html

If you are trying to make a page that works in a ton of mobile browsers, keep that chart close by.

If you are just looking for a way to make iphone specific mobile sites, you should check out [jqTouch](http://jqtouch.com/) and/or [XUI JS](http://xuijs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The mobile aspect really has to be considered at the outset. Good, well-planned, structured site with textual content designed to be compatible to be appropriate for reformatting, and tailor-made css for media=handheld is your best bet.

If you want to try something very mobile specific, what about WALL http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/java/wall.php?

Comment: have you used wufl ? looks interesting

Comment: I have avoided the user-agent recognition approach on purpose :D but I think that wurfl is a very good solution if you want to go that way – I believe that it has been used commercially and in academic communities (such as MIT Mobile) with much success. 

Personally, I prefer the re-purposable design approach, supporting only fully featured browsers on smartphones (mostly because I see the statistics on our servers :) )

Comment: Yes. I agree. It's better to concentrate on few popular devices and do it well, than to to them all in an average way. But good to know about this tool

Answer (score 1):

There are no tools that would magically produce the “right” HTML or CSS. When writing HTML and CSS for Mobile Safari you simply stick to standards, for example HTML4/5 and CSS2+. The hard part is the design, and I am afraid there is no automatic solution. You have to design around the platform’s shortcomings (no mouse cursor, for example) and play to its strengths. A good document about writing web sites and applications for Mobile Safari is the [Safari Web Content Guide](http://edr.euro.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/Introduction/Introduction.html) by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Dashcode IDE which comes as part of the Apple Developer Tools. It comes with  a collection of templates for creating web content to target the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

To counter Alex's point in his comment, you can certainly find an option for covering all markups and all quirks.

We've developed a mobile markup language (WAPL) that allows you to describe a site in XML, pass it via a web service and get the perfect markup back.

It's called Wapple Architect - and it really is better than anything you've used before.. more devices, more compatibility.. http://wapple.net